# How to find a point or number of points that represent an object inside a detected bounding box

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I'm working on object detection using YOLOv4 and I need to find a point or a number of points that actually represent the object inside detected bounding box. That point (or limited number of points/pixels) must be located on the object and not on the background within the Object Bounding Box. The center of the bounding box should be avoided as that can lie, in rare occasions, on the background. For example if a person raises his/her hand 90 degrees to his body, the contour surrounding him becomes concave curve.  For this and all concave-looking object the bounding box center can lie on the background and not on the object itself. Also I need to make this algorithm in real-time, so segmentation or
background subtraction might not work.

Thanks

Comment: What do you acutall mean by "represent an object"? What do you need to do with the extracted points?

Comment: @FilippoGrazioli Actually I want to add a marker ( let say red circle) to show that here is the object inside the bounding box. I dont want to draw this on the background (when a walking person is detected, the point should be on the person not on the ground).

Comment: I'm not sure this will be robust, but you might try to use the watershed segmentation on the bounding box crop (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) and the compute the centroid of the extracted blob (https://learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/)